# How to extract particular elements in xml data using Python elementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to extract some data from a large XML output, could someone help me extract the `TotalMilliseconds` for just the 99 percentile.

I am trying to do this in Python using the `ElementTree` parser.

I am currently trying to do something like this which finds the 99th percentile and then tries to find the `TotalMilliseconds` from the root of that level.

But this returns nothing, in debug I can see it gets into the 99 clause but I am bit lost on where I go from there.

```py
for item in root.findall('./TimeSpan/Latency/Bucket/Percentile'):
    if item.text == "99":
        totalMs = item.find('TotalMilliseconds').text
        print(totalMs)
```

```xml
<TimeSpan>
<Latency>
<Bucket>
<Percentile>96</Percentile>
<ReadMilliseconds>55.378</ReadMilliseconds>
<WriteMilliseconds>105.115</WriteMilliseconds>
<TotalMilliseconds>98.546</TotalMilliseconds>
</Bucket>
<Bucket>
<Percentile>97</Percentile>
<ReadMilliseconds>59.552</ReadMilliseconds>
<WriteMilliseconds>109.733</WriteMilliseconds>
<TotalMilliseconds>104.649</TotalMilliseconds>
</Bucket>
<Bucket>
<Percentile>98</Percentile>
<ReadMilliseconds>64.891</ReadMilliseconds>
<WriteMilliseconds>116.998</WriteMilliseconds>
<TotalMilliseconds>111.300</TotalMilliseconds>
</Bucket>
<Bucket>
<Percentile>99</Percentile>
<ReadMilliseconds>81.629</ReadMilliseconds>
<WriteMilliseconds>131.931</WriteMilliseconds>
<TotalMilliseconds>125.176</TotalMilliseconds>
</Bucket>
</Latency>
</TimeSpan>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of searching and iterating over the `Percentile` elements, iterate over the `Bucket` elements. Then, for each `Bucket`, find and compare its `Percentile` and proceed as you do already:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
    YOUR XML
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

for item in tree.findall(".//Bucket"):
    if item.find("Percentile").text == "99":
        totalMs = item.find("TotalMilliseconds").text
        print(totalMs)
```

Output:

```
125.176
```

Answer (score 2):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TimeSpan>
   <Latency>
      <Bucket>
         <Percentile>96</Percentile>
         <ReadMilliseconds>55.378</ReadMilliseconds>
         <WriteMilliseconds>105.115</WriteMilliseconds>
         <TotalMilliseconds>98.546</TotalMilliseconds>
      </Bucket>
      <Bucket>
         <Percentile>97</Percentile>
         <ReadMilliseconds>59.552</ReadMilliseconds>
         <WriteMilliseconds>109.733</WriteMilliseconds>
         <TotalMilliseconds>104.649</TotalMilliseconds>
      </Bucket>
      <Bucket>
         <Percentile>98</Percentile>
         <ReadMilliseconds>64.891</ReadMilliseconds>
         <WriteMilliseconds>116.998</WriteMilliseconds>
         <TotalMilliseconds>111.300</TotalMilliseconds>
      </Bucket>
      <Bucket>
         <Percentile>99</Percentile>
         <ReadMilliseconds>81.629</ReadMilliseconds>
         <WriteMilliseconds>131.931</WriteMilliseconds>
         <TotalMilliseconds>125.176</TotalMilliseconds>
      </Bucket>
   </Latency>
</TimeSpan>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
# data is a list to support the case of many 99 Percentile
data = [e.find('TotalMilliseconds').text for e in root.findall('.//Bucket') if e.find('Percentile').text == '99']
print(data)
```

output

```
['125.176']
```